# Running mod-wsgi code (.wsgi) with Apache2

Tags: apache, mod-wsgi

I'm using mod_wsgi on apache2/Mac OS X by setting apache server as follows.

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

<IfModule wsgi_module>
  WSGIScriptAlias /test /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/test.wsgi
</IfModule>
```

With this configuration, I could call test.wsgi with `http://.../test`

Now, I need to execute it by calling as follows.

`http://.../wsgi/test.wsgi`

I have the following code.

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi
</Directory>

<IfModule wsgi_module>
  WSGIScriptAlias /test /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/test.wsgi
  Alias /wsgi/ /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/
</IfModule>
```

I thought about using `Alias` so that I could link wsgi script directory to /wsgi/, and I expect Addhandler can handle the wsgi file, but it doesn't work.

What's wrong with my apache2 setup?

### SOLVED

```
<Directory /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts>
  Options ExecCGI Indexes
  AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
  AddHandler wsgi-script .wsgi

  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Directory>

Alias /wsgi/ /Library/WebServer/Documents/wsgi/scripts/
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use AddHandler with WSGIScriptAlias, you need to use AddHandler with Alias directive. You will need to set ExecCGI option as well for directory. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines